# urllib2 выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7, urllib

Добрый день.

Использую питон 2.7.5.
Пытаюсь отправить запрос в testrail:

```
from testrail.testrail import *

client = APIClient('https://testrail.xxxx.com/')
client.user = 'xxxx'
client.password = 'xxx'


result = client.send_post(
    'add_result_for_case/11099',
    {'status_id': 1, 'comment': 'something'}
)

print(result)
```

И получаю ошибку такого вида:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe D:/cache/testrailtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/cache/testrailtest.py", line 13, in <module>
    {'status_id': 1, 'comment': 'something'}
  File "D:\cache\testrail\testrail.py", line 52, in send_post
    return self.__send_request('POST', uri, data)
  File "D:\cache\testrail\testrail.py", line 65, in __send_request
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1167, in do_open
    h = http_class(host, timeout=req.timeout, **http_conn_args)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным ?

Comment: Ставьте питон 2.7.9 или новее

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос более не актуален. 
Каким-то образом либы различались по версиям.

Comment: Питоном. Аргумент `context` появился только в 2.7.9